# Error when making a socket chat

Tags: python, sockets, chat

I am making a chat using the socket library in python, it works, only half way though, when you netcat onto what I am using as a channel I am able to send messages and the other terminal is able to receive them, but, when that terminal sends a message (typing text, then hit enter) I do not receive it through the python script. So I ran it raw in the following way:
python shell:

```
import socket
sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(("127.0.0.1",8000)
sock.listen(2)
(client, (ip,port))=sock.accept()
```

Terminal:

```
nc 127.0.0.1 8000
```

This worked and to send or receive in the python shell all I had to do was type: sock.send("message") or sock.recv(2012)
Here is My code:

```
#!/bin/python
import socket
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import time
class color:
    r = '\033[31m'
    g = '\033[32m'
    d = '\033[0m'
    b = '\033[94m'
    p = '\033[35m'

def clear():
    print('\n' * 100)

chat_clients = []

sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clear()

def chatting_on_serverr():
        (client, (ip, port))=sock.accept()
    def chatting_on_server():
        message = raw_input("Send Message: ")
        client.send(message + '\n')
        client.recv(2012)
        chatting_on_server()
    chatting_on_server()

def make_channel():
    print color.b + '[+] '+color.d+'Welcome to the chat server'+color.b+' [+]'
    host = raw_input("Channel Name: ")
    port = input("Channel Access Key: ")
    clear()
    print color.p + "[info] "+color.b+"Making %s" % host
    time.sleep(1)
    sock.bind((host,port))
    sock.listen(3)
    print color.g + "[+] "+color.d+"Channel Made"+color.g+" [+]"+color.d
    print("[info]: Waiting for people to join your channel...")
    global chatting_on_serverr
    global chatting_on_server
    chatting_on_serverr()

clear()
make_channel()
```

Comment: What's with the global? And why a function inside a function? You could use a simple loop.

Comment: The global is there because without it I keep getting a error claiming that the chatting_on_server was mentioned earlier and, I got several parsing errors, they I believe are fine, but would a loop help with the unable to receive messages problem? If so please send an example @DoronCohen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that was needed to be done is to print the output of the .recv function
    x = client.recv(2020)
    print(x)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this on my machine because of network limitations but I recommend you to look at this [tutorial](http://www.binarytides.com/code-chat-application-server-client-sockets-python/) of a Python chat client and server. It will explain a lot about sockets and networking.

Beside that you shouldn't define globals with the same name as functions in your code. It might override their declaration. Another thing is the function inside the function. You can write that function like that:

```
def chatting_on_server():
    client, (ip, port) = sock.accept()
    while True:
        message = raw_input("Send Message: ")
        client.send(message + '\n')
        client.recv(2012)
```

And you will get the same functionality. Also, you risk yourself with a stack overflow error because `chatting_on_server` calls itself forever.

Good luck!

Comment: I see what you mean, and just tried it out, but sadly it has the same output, I can send and the receiver receives, but when the receiver sends a message no content is displayed on my end, it just loops back to the send message. @DoronCohen

Comment: I suggest you to read the tutorial I referenced and try it out, unless someone else can make your code work.